# Why does CNG only (seem to) support FIPS-approved AES-GCM decryption but not encryption?

Tags: aes-gcm, fips-140

The [Security Policy Document: Microsoft Windows FIPS 140 Validation](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3197.pdf) (version 1.4
dated May 7, 2020) mentions in section 2.2:

> 2.2 FIPS 140-2 Approved Algorithms
>
> Cryptographic Primitives Library implements the following FIPS-140-2 Approved algorithms:
>
> - NIST SP 800-38D AES-128, AES- 192, and AES-256 GCM decryption and GMAC

Note the explicit use of *decryption* and not *encryption*. Furthermore, section 2.3 says the following (where the meaning or purpose of the word *Mode* is unclear to me in this context ):

> 2.3 Non-Approved Algorithms
>
> Mode Cryptographic Primitives Library implements the following non-approved algorithms:
>
> - NIST SP 800-38D AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256 GCM encryption

Apparently a FIPS-approved version of AES-GCM encryption is not available. Trying to confirm this from NIST's Cryptographic Algorithm Validation Program (CAVP) certificates directly is not easy though. For example, taking [#C211](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/details?source=C&number=211) as the starting point, there are several references to AES-GCM but no distinction between encryption and decryption.

This lack of availability of encryption comes across as a severe restriction. For example it seems not possible to implement an encrypted two-way session with AES-GCM when operating in FIPS Mode. Is this really the case? If yes, what could be the rationale for such limitation?

---

Update: after a lot more searching, I found confirmation in actual NIST CMVP certificate pages that older versions of Windows did indeed only have AES-GCM decryption validated and not encryption. My conclusion is that the security policy document associated with the newer validations is an evolution of [an older policy document](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp2357.pdf) and that it was never properly updated to reflect the validation of the encryption side.

I am fairly convinced that this is a documentation error but I think only Microsoft can confirm that.

Comment: That is weird.  If you go and look at the individual certifications it does say that AES 128, 192 and 256 are validated for both encryption and decryption.  I don't even have a guess at what's going on there other than it's a mistake.  My company relies on Windows FIPS validations so this is of great interest to me.  I'll contact Microsoft about this Monday and see if I can get an answer.  If I do I'll post it here.

Comment: Which individual certifications are you referring to exactly? I have seen several but none of them mentioned both encryption and decryption explicitly.

Comment: Maybe just a typo there? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/fips-140-validation

Comment: Thanks @kelalaka. As you can see in my added update, I do now believe this is a documentation error. But that is a document directly referenced by the NIST CMVP certificate page -- a lousy place to be sloppy, in my opinion.

Comment: @Swashbuckler I added an update. I am very interested to hear what MS has to say about this indeed, thanks.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek sent the email.  We'll see what they say.